# Pullback of pushforward $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $g:X\rightarrow Y$ is any function and $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on X. Let $U$ be the push forward $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$.

i.e., $U=\{B\subset Y|g^{-1}(B)\in A\}$

Is the pull-back $\sigma$-algebra of U i.e., $A'=\{l\subset X|l=g^{-1}(B) ,B\in U\}$

equal to A?

I don't think its true but I can't find any counter examples.

I can show that $A'\subseteq A$ but I can't show that $A\subseteq A'$.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose $f$ and $g$ in your question are the same. Take $g$ to be a constant function and verify that $A'$ just consists of the empty set and the whole space whatever $A$ is .

Comment: Consider taking sequences of σ-algebras of this form (iterate pushing-forward then pulling-back or, alternatively, pulling-back then pushing-forward) or even, with g:X→X, sequences of push-forwards or pull-back (or mixed). Is this of any relevance? Thanks!

Comment: @LucasAmorim This may be of interest: Writing $g^*$ for the pullback map and $g_*$ for the pushforward map, the pair $(g^*, g_*)$ is an isotone Galois connection (i.e., a poset adjunction) between the family of all $\sigma$-algebras on $Y$ and the family of all $\sigma$-algebras on $X$ (easy to prove from the definitions). It follows that $g^* \circ g_* \circ g^* = g^*$ and $g_* \circ g^* \circ g_* = g_*$ (the "cancellation rule").